# Designing and displaying properly formatted data on django.

Tags: django, database

I am trying to make a model for a Blog and trying to format it in my template. Currently I have a single field for the "Body" of the blog, which will have all the content, but whenever I embed it in my template using

```
{% for i in blog %}
    {{ i.body }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now if there was a link in the blog or an image or a piece of code I can't format it accordingly because all the data inside the Column `body` gets embedded as a big block of string. I have tried to change my model into having
10 different `TextFields` for both body and sub heading of the blog. I also have different TextFields for links and this is how the end model looks, can someone tell me whether this is the right way to do it or not.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    para1 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subheading1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    para2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subheading2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    para3 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subheading3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    para4 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subheading4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    para5 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    codeblock = models.ForeignKey('blog.Code', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(null=True)
    headliner = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using different field for each paragraph, which is not a good practice you can store in `body` field html formatted value like this:

```
<H3>Title</H3><br>
<i>Some text</i>
```

To render such body correctly you can use [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter in your template:

```
{% for i in blog %}
    {{ i.body|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note `safe` filter disable html escaping, so you should use it only if source of `body` value is trusted.

**UPD**

If you need to format specific part of text yu can write [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) something like this:

```
def bold_some_text(value): # Only one argument.
    return value.replace('Some text', '<b>Some text</b>', 1)
```

And use this new tag with `safe`:

```
{% for i in blog %}
    {{ i.body|bold_some_text|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am familiar with formatting the data from the model but what if the Blog contains some text that I want formatted differently for example in between a 1000 words blog, and there's one sentence that I want to be Bold how do I separate out that one sentence and format it specifically. I apologize for the misleading question.

Comment: @Sahil Ah, in this case try to use custom template filter. Check updated answer.

Comment: That works perfectly. I didn't know you could do that. Thank you